# Converting PNG image into XImage format

Tags: image, c++14, x11, opencv3.0, xorg

I want to load a .png image (using OpenCV) and copy it to a new window using XPutImage(). But for that I have to first convert the image into XImage format.

I was able to do XImage to .png using the below code snippet. But now I am confused about the backward conversion.

So is there a good method (or code snippet) to convert a png file into XImage format ?

For XPutImage():
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XPutImage.html

```
 Mat img(ht,wd,CV_8UC3);

 XImage *image = XGetImage(d, w1, 0,0 , wd, ht, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
 unsigned long rm = image->red_mask;
 unsigned long gm = image->green_mask;
 unsigned long bm = image->blue_mask;

 for (int x = 0; x < wd; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < ht ; y++)
        {

        unsigned long pixel = XGetPixel(image,x,y);
        unsigned char blue = pixel & bm;
        unsigned char green = (pixel & gm) >> 8;
        unsigned char red = (pixel & rm) >> 16;     

        Vec3b color = img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y));         
                color[0] = blue;
        color[1] = green;
        color[2] = red;
        img.at<Vec3b>(Point(x,y)) = color;

    }   

imwrite("w1_img.png", img);
```